# Get last checked in time in each driver id

Tags: mysql

There is a table like below (table name --> DriverLocation). It has driverID and last checked in date time.
I need to query to get last checked in time in each driver.

```
DriverID    DateTime
=======     =========
2           2018-04-30 12:38:04 //Need
3           2018-04-30 11:26:04 //Need
1           2018-04-30 10:33:04 //Need
3           2018-04-30 10:15:04
4           2018-04-30 10:05:04 //Need
2           2018-04-30 09:22:04
3           2018-04-30 08:10:04
4           2018-04-30 08:09:04
1           2018-04-30 07:45:04
5           2018-04-30 07:31:04 //Need
4           2018-04-30 07:24:04
1           2018-04-30 06:53:04
3           2018-04-30 06:45:04
1           2018-04-30 05:33:04
2           2018-04-30 04:29:04
```

Final Dataset should be like this.

```
DriverID    DateTime
=======     =========
2           2018-04-30 12:38:04 //Need
3           2018-04-30 11:26:04 //Need
1           2018-04-30 10:33:04 //Need
4           2018-04-30 10:05:04 //Need
5           2018-04-30 07:31:04 //Need
```

I have no idea how to query to this kind of dataset. Please give me a direction to do this.

Comment: which data type ise the column DateTime  .,.and what is the //need  string right the date ..?

Comment: @scaisedge someone's not had their coffee this morning!

Comment: what have you tried before coming to SO?

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY and the MAX() function on your datetime column:

```
SELECT DriverID, MAX(last_checked)
FROM DriverLocation
GROUP BY DriverID
```

Answer (score 0):

If the //Need is not part of the DateTime column
you could use

```
   select DriverID, max(DateTime)
   from my_table  
   group by DriverID
   order by max(DateTime) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with ( replace DateTime with whatever your column name really is ) :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( SELECT * FROM DriverLocation ORDER BY DateTime DESC) t
GROUP BY t.DriverID
```

GROUP BY takes first row when grouping, your table being pre-order by most recent date, it will do the trick